# Fit table into one column for IEEE

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I am trying to fit this table into one column but not possible...

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{XcccXX}
    \toprule
    Item Name & Quantity & Item Price & Total Price & Supplier & Part Number \\
    \midrule
    Coilcraft Fixed Inductor \SI{10}{\milli\henry} & 1 & 0.71 & 0.71 & Mouser Electronics & 994-RFC0807B-106KE \\
    Bourns Fixed Inductor \SI{500}{\micro\henry} & 1 & 1.38 & 1.38 & Mouser Electronics & 542-5256-
    ON Semiconductor Diode & 4 & 0.08 & 0.32 & Mouser Electronics & 512-1N4148 \\
    Murata \SI{10}{\micro\farad} Capacitor  & 2 & 0.16 & 0.32 & Mouser Electronics & 81-GRM155C80G106ME44 \\
    Alpha \SI{1}{\kilo\ohm} Potentiometer & 1 & 1.47 & 1.47 & Mouser Electronics & 313-1000f-1K \\
  KEMET \SI{0.1}{\micro\farad} Capacitor & 2 & 0.56 & 1.12 & Mouser Electronics & 80-C0805X104K4RAUTO \\
  Bourns \SI{200}{\kilo\ohm} Potentiometer & 1 & 0.83 & 0.83 & Mouser Electronics & 652-PDB12-F4201204BF \\
    TT Electronics \SI{10}{\kilo\ohm} Potentiometer & 1 & 0.77 & 0.77 & Mouser Electronics & 858-P160KN-0QC17B10K \\
    Vishay \SI{1}{\kilo\ohm} Resistor & 1 & 0.25 & 0.25 & Mouser Electronics & 71-RCS12061K00FKEA \\  
    TE Connectivity \SI{11}{\kilo\ohm}  Resistor & 1 & 0.34 & 0.34 & Mouser Electronics & 279-ROX5SSJ11K \\
    Analogue Devices Inc. AD8666 Op-amp & 1 & 1.05 & 1.05 & Digi-Key & AD8666ARZ-REELTR-ND \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I really need this in one column only. Any way to do that? Possibly, [Display table nicely and better code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470861/display-table-nicely-and-better-code), they did some symbols, so maybe add symbol for supplier on item name and then have a key below? Or any other way to fit in one column on IEEEtran journal class?

Comment: Welcome! Please post a *complete* code.

Comment: That's perfect!

Comment: Note, you really should use [ht] instead of [H], just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{seqsplit, collcell, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash\collectcell\seqsplit}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{>{\RaggedRight}X@{}ccc>{\RaggedRight}X@{}Y}
    \toprule
    Item Name & Quantity & \thead{Item\\ Price} & \thead{Total\\Price} & Supplier & Part Number \\
    \midrule
    Coilcraft Fixed Inductor \SI{10}{\milli\henry} & 1 & 0.71 & 0.71 & Mouser Electronics & 994-RFC0807B-106KE \\
    Bourns Fixed Inductor \SI{500}{\micro\henry} & 1 & 1.38 & 1.38 & Mouser Electronics & 542-5256- \\
 ON Semiconductor Diode & 4 & 0.08 & 0.32 & Mouser Electronics & 512-1N4148 \\
 Murata \SI{10}{\micro\farad} Capacitor & 2 & 0.16 & 0.32 & Mouser Electronics & 81-GRM155C80G106ME44 \\
 Alpha \SI{1}{\kilo\ohm} Potentiometer & 1 & 1.47 & 1.47 & Mouser Electronics & 313-1000f-1K \\
 KEMET \SI{0.1}{\micro\farad} Capacitor & 2 & 0.56 & 1.12 & Mouser Electronics & 80-C0805X104K4RAUTO \\
 Bourns \SI{200}{\kilo\ohm} Potentiometer & 1 & 0.83 & 0.83 & Mouser Electronics & 652-PDB12-F4201204BF \\
 TT Electronics \SI{10}{\kilo\ohm} Potentiometer & 1 & 0.77 & 0.77 & Mouser Electronics & 858-P160KN-0QC17B10K \\
 Vishay \SI{1}{\kilo\ohm} Resistor & 1 & 0.25 & 0.25 & Mouser Electronics & 71-RCS12061K00FKEA \\
 TE Connectivity \SI{11}{\kilo\ohm} Resistor & 1 & 0.34 & 0.34 & Mouser Electronics & 279-ROX5SSJ11K \\
 Analogue Devices Inc. AD8666 Op-amp & 1 & 1.05 & 1.05 & Digi-Key & AD8666ARZ-REELTR-ND \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much for this morning...but I have delete my answer because there is a little problem of space. :-)